# Woocommerce Cart won't update after changing quantity and clicking Update Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I change the cart quantity and then click the Update Cart button, the price does not update. If I click the Update Cart button again, then it works as it should. Anyone have an idea as to why this might be occurring?

http://cmscolorado.staging.wpengine.com/cart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error appearing in the console when I try and update the product quantity on the cart page.

```
Failed to load https://cmscolorado.staging.wpengine.com/cart/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cmscolorado.staging.wpengine.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Research how to fix that and your cart should work again.

Comment: I will take a look. Thank you

Comment: Seeing what it was trying to load versus its origins, I saw that I wasn't testing with https. Once I used ssl the issue went away. Thanks for the Error.

Comment: You're welcome.  Always remember to check your debug.log and console for errors the answers are usually there.